# CAMetalLayer is only available on iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, rendering, metal

I am using `CAMetalLayer` to draw onto a UIView.
The compiler throws a warning that `CAMetalLayer` is only available on iOS 13.0.
The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer) however say `iOS 8.0+`.
Can I ignore this warning? I only have iOS 13.0 devices here and we'd like to support 12 and 11, too.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CAMetalLayer` is actually available on **iOS 8.0+**, I can confirm this. This warning is a known Apple mistake, you can ignore it.

Comment: Is there a way to silence the warning thus to not add noise to my build?

Comment: Unfortunately in Swift, this isn’t just a warning, but an error. I put `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = 13.0` into my `.xcconfig` file, but as the `CAMetalLayer` is inside a Swift module, this doesn’t work. The only only options I see are to bump up the minimum OS version or stop using the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

This normally happens when compiling with a pre-iOS 13 deployment target for the Simulator. You'll notice if you click through the warning that you see headers from the Simulator SDK:

[image: The CAMetalLayer header for the Simulator shows that the class is explicitly marked as available from iOS 13, when Metal became supported in the Simulator.]

You shouldn't receive this diagnostic when compiling for a device.